# Storing table and column names in html

Tags: jquery, html, mysql

I'm currently working on a system that outputs many input fields to a page. In order to keep a track of where the values need to be stored in the database, the HTML looks something like this:

```
<input id="foobar" data-table="foo" data-column="bar" />
```

the jQuery then uses `.data('table')` and `.data('column')` as arguments that are passed server side to direct the values to the relevant table/column.

---

**Q:** Even with everything being properly escaped etc. on server-side, is this a security risk? Is exposing the table and column names in the html making the page more liable to an attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a execellent discussion about this topic:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/109961/exposing-database-fields-names-in-html

One quote:

> It is very common to do this. As you've noticed, there is a
>   significant benefit for keeping code simple.
>
> If you do have an SQL injection vulnerability, an attacker can figure
>   out your database structure using INFORMATION_SCHEMA. So hiding your
>   database structure doesn't help you a great deal.
>
> Another concern in this area is Mass assignment vulnerabilities.
>   Perhaps a user is allowed to update their user details - name, email,
>   password, etc. But they are not supposed to be able to update the
>   field "is_admin". With code that automatically routes form fields to
>   SQL statements, sometimes vulnerabilities like this can appear.

So while this might remove a tiny bit of security layer on top (by presenting a part of a attack surface to an potential attacker), it shouldn't be that big of a deal as long as the rest of your application is properly secured.

Comment: The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` comment is only true if the SQL Injection vulnerability allows the attacker to retrieve data.  Sometimes it's a one-way injection and I'm just sending raw/random strings trying to figure out column names that will allow an "UPDATE" to work.  Err I mean, the attacker...

Answer (score 2):

A security risk can mean lots of things.  As far as SQL injection, IF you are properly escaping everything (or using parameterized queries), it should be fine.

If you consider people knowing certain details of your database schema a security risk, then yes, it is.  For example, if someone found another place on your app that was vulnerable, now they can determine the schema and attack with better precision instead of just guessing table names.

If you're quite sure everything is secure, it's probably not a big deal (but do we ever REALLY know that?...)

tl;dr; maybe... maybe not... probably not a big deal

Answer (score 0):

Using table and column name in html make it possible to see by anyone from page source. Why you let the other people see the table and column name. It should be avoided.